# Google Sheets Script to Return Specific Text Based on Specific Text from Adjacent Cell

Tags: google-apps-script

first post, thanks in advance for any help.

I have a fair amount of experience creating spreadsheets with included formulas, but I'm a total newb when it comes to Google Scripts. I'm assuming that what I'm trying to accomplish is relatively common and simple, but I can't find the answer.

All I want to do is have the cells column B return specific text if a specific text is entered into the adjacent cells in column A.
If that specific text is NOT entered into column A, then column B should remain (or go back to being) freely editable. This would need to apply to the entire column(s)/ranges.

I'm pretty sure this would involve the onEdit trigger, but I have never used Google Scripts and I don't know how to write that script. Would anyone would be so kind as to assist me with this?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please review [How to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You should make some effort to address this on your own rather than ask someone to do it for you. Nothing in your question is very complex, the only reason you aren't finding anything is because you're trying to do it all at once. Break down your objectives into smaller chunks:  How to get a cell value, how to change a cell value, how to write an if statement, how to loop through values or cells, how to setup the onEdit trigger. There are countless examples of each these all of the internet.

Answer (score 0):

#### An onEdit function Based upon what you described

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName() == "Sheet Name" && e.range.columStart == 1 && e.value == "Specific Text") {
    e.range.offset(0,1).setValue('Specific Text');
  }
}
```

You need to update Sheet Name and Specific Text. You cannot run this type of function without supplying the event object which normally comes from the onEdit trigger.  So this function cannot be from the script editor or a menu.